# Remove all replicated values in array, only keeping the unique key/value pair

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove all the replicated values in an array, only keeping the remaining unique key/value? `array_unique` isn't the solution.

For example, I have the following array.

```
Array
(
    [169580] => 1901
    [209662] => 2245
    [209682] => 1901
)
```

I want to compare all values in array and remove both `[169580] => 1901` and `[209682] => 1901` and keep `[209662] => 2245` in the array.  The 'key' is an unknown value that I cannot search for.

Final result will look like the following:

```
Array
(
    [209662] => 2245
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to group by values, then create the result by taking the key/value pair from groups that have only one key.

```
// group
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $values[$value][] = $key;
}
// filter
foreach ($values as $value => $keys) {
    if (count($keys) == 1) $result[$keys[0]] = $value;
}
```

---

An approximate equivalent of this algorithm using array functions (similar to what the other answer shows) rather than loops is like this:

```
// group
$counts = array_count_values($array);
// filter
$result = array_filter($array, function($value) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$value] == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple `array_` functions to accomplish this: `array_count_values()` to create a frequency count lookup table and `array_filter` on the original array to remove keys with `count !== 1`.

```
$arr = [
  "169580" => 1901,
  "209662" => 2245,
  "209682" => 1901
];

$lookup = array_count_values($arr);

print_r(array_filter($arr, function ($e) use ($lookup) {
    return $lookup[$e] == 1;
}));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [209662] => 2245
)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/SuperficialAwesomeHashfunction)

Comment: Good idea! `array_count_values` is handy for this. I was working on editing my answer to add a similar solution when you posted this. I just wanted to specifically mention it to you so it wouldn't appear that I was stealing your idea. +1 :-)

Comment: Your version is a lot cleaner. +1!